# Url does not contain a definition for IsLocalUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i'm using Visual studio 2015 update 3 and i'm trying to use `Url.IsLocalUrl` & `Url.Action`  but i get this error

> url does not contain a definition for IsLocalUrl

got the same error for `Url.Action`

[image]

how can i use these?

Comment: Show how you use it.

Comment: @mwisnicki edited the Question

Comment: What version of .net and MVC are you targeting?

Comment: @LDJ i guess  it's mvc 5

Comment: 1.Go to your reference folder
2.look for system.web.mvc
3.Right Click on it
4.Click Properties
5.Look at the Version property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the image, my best guess is your `GetRedirectUrl` method is not wrapped inside `Aouth1Controller : Controller` class.

Just check the `{}` carefully then it should appear.
The `Url.IsLocalUrl` & `Url.Action` are belonged to `UrlHelper` class, which only can be called if you inherit `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` or define a new `UrlHelper`